# trying to print pyramid using JavaScript on html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print `#` in pyramid form using JavaScript and print it in an HTML `div`. But the problem is I am only able to print the last row of `#` pyramid. So help needed.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var ck="";
    for(var string="#";string <="#######";string=string + "#")
    {
        ck= "<h" + 2 + "> " + string + "</h" + 2 + "><br>";
    } 
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=ck;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" > <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep replacing the content in the variable

```
ck= "..."
```

So every iteration you keep overwriting it.

You need to concat to the string

```
 ck = ck + "...";
```

or

```
ck += "...";
```

Next your for loop is incorrect, it should have numbers not characters. It works but, it is very strange to do it that way.